# In a functional component, how can I perform a pure transformation of props before rendering them?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm quite new to Vue, and a problem I'm facing right now is defining a functional Vue component that represents an individual grid tile.

This component renders as a single `div` element. It takes two props representing its x/y position in the grid and needs to use these two props to figure out the CSS classes to apply to the `div`. Essentially, I just need a way to run these props through a pure function that produces a `classObject` which I can then v-bind to the `class` attribute of the `div`.

Below is the template and component logic I've defined in `GridSquare.vue`:

```html
<template functional>
  <div :class="classObject(props)"></div>
</template>
```

```typescript
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: {
    xIndex: Number,
    yIndex: Number
  },
  methods: {
    classObject(props) {
      const { xIndex, yIndex } = props;

      return {
        normal: true,
        "thick-left": xIndex % 10 === 0,
        "thick-top": yIndex % 10 === 0,
        "thick-right": (xIndex + 1) % 10 === 0,
        "thick-bottom": (yIndex + 1) % 10 === 0
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

However, this doesn't work: all I see is blank space where the `div` elements should be, and errors in my console like this:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1737 TypeError: _vm.classObject is not a function

To summarise, I'm just looking for a way to process props into a different object and then making use of that in my template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now. You can track [this related issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1291).

You'll have to write the render function manually.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. That's a huge limitation. Thanks for pointing it out though - I'll accept when it permits me. I've thought of a better way of achieving what I'm trying to so hopefully I can work around this anyway.